# Summing based on vertical and horizontal criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to sum values based on row and column conditions but can't quite figure it out.  I feel like I am close.  I have tried a bunch of different things but the closest I have come is using

```
=arrayformula(sum(if(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$2 = B2, if(Sheet2!$A$2:$A = A2, Sheet2!$B$2:$D))))
```

I have a [sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LQQrZcM_iQ0wNqQXgBqWnkwz-KsvmHTTku-b7DF9lzY/edit#gid=0)

This currently doesn't work as an arrayformula but if I drag it down it find the values for week 1 but the rest of the weeks it shows a 0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think `$B$2:$D$2 = B12` or similar would work. Could you explain what are you trying to do, step by step?

Comment: Given your sample sheet, it doesn't look like you need a `SUM` function, maybe `index(match())` will provide the solution?

Comment: I definitely overthought this.  I went the way of index(match()) and it worker perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to read that. Could you or @a-burge post the full formula you used as solution as an answer? For Stackoverflow workflow purposes :)

Comment: Just looked at the sheet, looks like the problem could be related to the _type_ of the week number. Sometimes they are values, and sometimes strings, which will throw off all comparison formulas. Try naming those "week X" instead and see what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are already aggregated then index match will do the trick:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$D$5,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH(C2,Sheet2!$B$1:$D$1,0))`